# How call python to run script on $PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, environment-variables, spaces

My $PATH environment variable has /a/path/with spaces/in/it, upon which sits a python script I want to run from a different location.

But when I try to run it with python3 I get a file not found error.

```
$ python3 prog.py

python3: can't open file 'prog.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The same happens when I attempt to apply the linux file command to it:

```
$ file prog.py

prog.py: cannot open `prog.py' (No such file or directory)
```

Yet if I type the name of bash scripts on the same path, they run as expected.

Similarly, if I just type prog.py, my shell attempts to run it. So my system can see the file perfectly well.

What's more, If I cd to the actual location of prog.py, then tell python3 to run it, it executes as it ought.

Why does this happen, or fail to happen as they case may be?

And how can I execute the command as I wish?

Comment: it's not a path issue at all. it's just that `python` prefix doesn't look for commands in the PATH.

Comment: try `python3 ./prog.py`.

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262018/echo-path-shows-path-to-python-scripts-but-they-cannot-be-executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was to attribute the python script properly as an executable.

(As described in the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262018/echo-path-shows-path-to-python-scripts-but-they-cannot-be-executed) provided in the comment above by Jean-François Fabre, and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409284/how-apply-command-to-file-on-path-with-spaces)).

That is, to have `#! /usr/bin/python3` as the first line of the script, in addition to making it an executable, and then simply calling it to run it.